# Raspberry can't read usb and the cpu is really hot

Tags: raspberry-pi

i need help for my raspberry pi B+
Yesterday my raspberry can boot and used perfectly. But just now my raspberry can't read my usb mouse and usb keyboard. And the most terrifying is raspberry cpu is really hot, i dont know what happen to my raspberry. I'm using adaptor for 5V and 1A for supplying my raspberry, and before that tragedy happen, i'm mounting my sensor, LCD 20x4 and anything else that worked perfectly. Can someone explain to me, what's going on my raspberry and what can i do to fix it?  :(

Comment: It sounds like something is taking up a lot of system resources, so your processor is working hard to try and keep up. Try plugging it in to a monitor on HDMI, and just plugging in the keyboard, then see if it'll boot up and respond to the keyboard. Get to a console (alt + shift + f1) and type `top`, this will show if an application is using up a lot of CPU (if so, this will be at the top of the list).

Comment: but my raspberry still doesn't want to recognizes my keyboard, how can i do it?

Comment: The first check is a simple one, try the keyboard on another computer, or try another keyboard, if you can. There could be an issue with it. Otherwise, I don't know that I can help.

Comment: Depending on your OS, you should be able to use SSH to remote log in.

Comment: i 'm not using SSH, i plug it directly on monitor

Comment: You can SSH into your Pi to monitor the processes and/or CPU

Comment: what is indicators the cpu that i must to check?

Comment: AJFaraday tell it, it is called `top`, or `htop`. The processor usage means heat... You need to fix this issue if you pretend to have your RPi more than two years.....

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem like You.

Power Supply - I recommended 5V 2A Power Supply 2) And Network ethernet patch cable shielded (with shield or ground line).

Then try another keyboard or mouse.
As is written above login to your R-Pi via SSH.
Install HTOP : sudo apt-get install htop
And watch what is eating your CPU.